# Azure DevOps Making Work Item Field Required when Iteration is changed

Tags: azure-devops, rules, azure-boards

I am looking to setup a condition in Azure DevOps, where if a specific work item type has a change to the iteration after creation, one of the fields in the Details tab is required. Currently I am only able to make it required based on the status of the work item changing.

When creating the condition, I do not have the capability to select a condition of "When 'The iteration changes'", "Then 'Make required' ".